# Change Static library header to private

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, header-files

I have created a static library in Xcode, all is well.
This static library contains two public headers, which are accessible to users who use this static library.

I want to remove one of these headers, so that only one of the headers will be accessible.
Now, the problem is that the header which i want to make a private header is extremely not cooperative...

I have removed it from:
1. the static library main header file.
2. the Target's Build Phases -> copy headers (moved from 'public' to 'project').
3. other places where it may be 'lazily' imported in other .h files.

after that, i have build the project-library, and linked the new library to a project which uses it. to my utter surprise, i could still call the header file which i have tried to make private.

I have preformed the same actions while actually deleting the file (.h && .m), still with the same results.

Any ideas? all help will be greatly appreciated.